# Установка модуля PHP Windows 7 Starter

Tags: установка, windows, php

Здравствуйте! Такая беда: установила модуль PHP на Windows 7 (сервер ставила Apache 2.2), мучилась со связями, но поставила и все работает. А на Windows 7 Starter модуль не ставится (сервер поставился нормально). Почему? Вообще возможно ли его на Starter установить?

Comment: Напишите алгоритм действий, которыми Вы подключаете новый модуль: так можно будет найти ошибку.  
На винду стартер спокойно устанавливается пшп со всеми модулями.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте [комплект Денвер](http://www.denwer.ru/), там все встанет как нужно.

Comment: Да я их и вручную связала,все работает. Но на Windows7 полной. А на Windows Starter не становится. Почему? Потому что Windows Starter не серверная платформа? Или можно и на Starter установить и я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: win7 в любой реализации как бы не серверная платформа. однако, в стартере есть ограничение на количество одновременно запущенных пользовательских приложений (не более 5), скорее всего оно и срабатывает.

Comment: Это ограничение они сняли еще в 2009 году...  
У меня на нетбуке со стартером запускается любое количество приложений.

Comment: Просто последовательность действий одинаковую делаю. Только на одном все поставилось (и сервер, и модуль PHP, и MySQL),а на втором,т.е на Startere,сервер работает нормально,а модули не ставится. Пишет большую "жалобу",что требуемая операция не может быть выполнена,попробуйте еще раз. Что-то в этом роде. Вы хотите сказать,что есть смысл закрыть все программы и попробовать установить еще раз?

Comment: скорее всего, W7Starter не даст корректно работать из-за своей ограниченности